# Only has children .write rule [Firebase]

Tags: firebase

Given the following rule:

```
   {
    "rules": {
        "users": {
           "$uid": {
              "name":{
                ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
              }
           }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way in Firebase to limit the children that can be written to an object?

For example I would like to limit the client to writing this object with only one attribute:

```
name {
  "value": "value"
}
```

I know there is `.validate` and `hasChildren()` but it doesn't prevent a user to legally write an object under $uid with undesired attributes.

Nothing is preventing the client from writing an object as follows:

```
name {
  "value":"value",
  "unwantedAttribute":"wastingSpace"
}
```

Is there an equivalent to `hasThoseChildrenOnly()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.write` rule determines **who** can write data to a location, not **what** data they can write.

To determine the structure of the data written, you'll need a `.validate` rule. In this case you can say that a `name` is required and must be a string with:

```
{
  ".validate": "newData.hasChild('name')",
  "name": {
    ".validate": "newData.isString()"
  },
  "$other": {
    ".validate": false
  }
}
```

The validate on the top-level ensures that new data must always have a `name` property. Without this, you can delete the `name`, because deleting data does not trigger validation.

The second validate ensures that `name` is a string.

The third validation ensures that any child but `name` will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

@Frank van Puffelen's answer is really helpful, but I'd like point out one more thing.

From [the Firebase documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters),

> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is **failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location** that grants access. Even if every affected child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely.

So it would be better to state `.read` and `.write` permission on your parents node.