# Firebase rules with wildcards to read data if wildcard is known

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, wildcard, firebase-security

I have sign up system where I want only users to sign up if they have a valid secret key which I shall provide to users who want to register. If key is in db, then proceed to sign up. Thus I have generated random non repeated 8 chars and stored them in the real time database in the following structure:

```
Secrets:
 "x5f1n9v0":
     "Status" : 1
 "C8vT2xxY":
     "Status" : 1
And so on
```

..

```
{
  "rules": {
    "secrets":{
      "$secret": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

First question regarding the aboves rules:-
    In this case no one can add a new secret key ?
    Also the read will only be valid if someone has a valid key from my list ? Nobody can read the whole list ? Any bugs in this ?

Now suppose another set of rules where I want to write to the child of each key iff the user knows the valid id.

If I change the rule for write to true, will this work and no bugs to hack it ?

```
  "rules": {
    "secrets":{
      "$secret": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are really way too many questions here. I'll try to answer below, but please limit yourself to a single question in the future. (not the downvoter by the way, although I can imagine that might be the reason)

Comment: Actually I don't know why I got a down vote. Maybe for the last stupid question but I see that my post was well arranged and to the point and I got clear answers as well from you. I can not actually post anymore and got banned. Anyway thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case no one can add a new secret key?

With those first rules, only someone with administrative access can add keys.

> Also the read will only be valid if someone has a valid key from my list? Nobody can read the whole list?

There is indeed no way to read the entire list with your first set of rules. Someone can only read a secret if they know its key.

With your second set of rules:

```
"secrets":{
  "$secret": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Now anyone can write any secret. That is probably not what you want. If you want to only allow them to change the data that already exists under an existing key, you'll want to check if there is any data already:

```
"secrets":{
  "$secret": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "data.exists()"
  }
}
```

If you want them to not be able to change-but-not-delete the existing data, that would be `data.exists() && newData.exists()`. If you have additional requirements about the data formats users can write, you'll want to add those to a corresponding `.validate` rule.

Your last set of rules is both invalid and meaningless. It's invalid because `$secrets` is not defined. But even if it was defined `$secrets === $secrets` will always be `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and clear answer. It is clear for me now and answered all my qiestions.

Comment: Hi again, the rule for adding data.exists() denied the create of a new key, but anybody now can still create sub lists inside the key if it is known.
firebasedb.ref('secrets/$key/email/values/another/sub/list').set("spam");
N.B: I changed the structure to include email & isValid under the key.
I tried your solution here but it failed with me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36782496/9574544

Comment: If you want to enforce a certain data structure, you'll need to add `.validate` rules for that. If you're having trouble making those work, open a new question with the [minimal JSON + rules that reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks. I will try to ask again when I am not blocked.